# Слушать SMTP сервер mail.ru

Tags: c#, сокет, mail.ru

Пытаюсь написать программу, которая будет слушать СМТП-сервер mail.ru (в учебных целях). Т.е. когда отправляется сообщение, софт перехватывает сообщение и делает свои дейсвтия (пишет логи, учебные же цели).

> Сервер исходящей почты (SMTP-сервер) — smtp.mail.ru (адрес:
>   217.69.139.160)
>
> Порт  SMTP — 465

**Код приложения:**

```
address = IPAddress.Parse("217.69.139.160");
port = 465;

IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(address, port);
TcpListener Listener = new TcpListener(ipep);
Listener.Start(); // Тут ошибка: Требуемый адрес для своего контекста неверен
```

**Вопрос: верно ли я поступаю для этих целей? Как можно убрать эту ошибку - может адрес не тот?**

Спасибо

Comment: SMTP сервер smtp.mail.ru живет на 25 порту, не смотря на то, что SSL и на то что пишут в инструкциях 465

Comment: @Dmitry,  попробовал, все равно та же ошибка - Требуемый адрес для своего контекста неверен. Сам адрес правильный?

Comment: ну могу сказать, что ответ вам уже дан, про winpcam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы неправильно формулируете задачу. Соответственно и инструменты выбираете неправильные. Слушают порт, а не сервер. Слушатель и есть сервером. В вашем случае необходимо перехватывать сетевой трафик, анализировать перехваченные пакеты, фильтровать их, отбирая нужные. То-есть сетевые пакеты будут сначала попадать в Ваш перехватчик а потом уже двигаться далее по обычному маршруту. Для этих целей можно воспользоваться библиотекой [winpcap](http://www.winpcap.org/).

Comment: Согласен, ошибка в формулировании задачи.